# cvitem \hbox overfull in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

Is it possible to change the length or size of the box where the first text is placed in \cvitem{this text is too long}{...}

I doesn't fit and it looks kinda stupid. I get this message:

```
Overfull \hbox (6.6563pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 102--102
```

So is it possible to add 6.6563pt points of lenght to the first box in \cvitems entry.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 


\moderncvstyle{classic}                           
\moderncvcolor{blue}                               

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\section{Basic info}
\cvitem{this is fine}{derp}
\cvitem{verylongworddd}{Derpderpdep}
\end{document}
```

The second item is a bit too long and doesn't fit into the cvitem box. Can I make the word fit there and align better.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of the left column is stored in the parameter

```
\hintscolumnwidth
```

The width of the right column is computed using this one, so you can do

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\addtolength{\hintscolumnwidth}{6.7pt}

\name{John}{Doe}


\begin{document}
\section{Basic info}
\cvitem{this is fine}{derp}
\cvitem{verylongworddd}{Derpderpdep}

\end{document}
```

Use a bit more than the maximum overfull you get during the previous run. Hopefully this won't ruin paragraphs in the right hand column.